# Cannot reach internet when connected directly to modem

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking, dhcp, modem

I am currently attempting to diagnose bandwidth issues in my home network setup. I am seeing some strange throughput behavior and thus am trying to remove my WLAN router from the equation to try to label the weak link. Normal setup is `SB6183 modem` -> `WLAN router` -> `PC`, all hardwired (for testing, at least). In this setup, the router properly DHCPs with the ISP and then serves as DHCP server for my LAN.

The trouble arises when I attempt to directly connect my PC to my modem, to cut out the router. I can't get my PC (Win10 host) to properly DHCP and pull a public IP from my ISP/modem. I tried setting a static config (IP, subnet, gateway, and DNS) to the exact same as what my router was getting from DHCP, but that still didn't work. With the static config, I was able to ping the ISP gateway but not 8.8.8.8 or anything else on the internet. I've tried with 2 other Windows PCs and gotten the same behavior on all of them.

I am hesitant to turn off the Windows firewall - I don't really see that being the issue though since I'm not even completing a DHCP handshake. I could try this on a Ubuntu box, but doesn't seem like it would be OS-specific either.

Anyone have thoughts on what might be wrong or other configuration options to try? All suggestions are appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You might need to power cycle the modem, as they cache the MAC of the last device.

Comment: Sounds like a case of MAC address registration. This is really a problem your ISP should be helping you with.

Comment: Could you add the output of the command `ipconfig` to your post?

Comment: Was the router pre-configured by your ISP? (Some ISPs require VLAN tagging.)

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, a while back, my ISP Modem did not have a router built in and the IP address had to be the external ISP address. See if that may be the issue.

Comment: It might be that your modem is in bridge mode. In that case it will deactivate LAN ports 2 and up, so make sure you connect your pc to LAN 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments, this did appear to be a MAC caching issues with the modem. Power cycling after disconnect cleared the cache and allowed DHCP to work properly for the new device.

Thanks all for the help!